# Dennis Ritchie citation for "the C declarator syntax is an experiment that failed"?

Tags: programming-languages, history, c, syntax

I've often heard that the C declarator syntax described as "an experiment that failed." I've seen claims that this sentiment is also shared by its creator Dennis Ritchie. Does anybody have an actual citation for this?

I'm doing a related project and writing the documentation for it and it would be nice to have said citation.

FWIW, I have found where Bjarne Stroustrup said it during a Slashdot [interview](http://www.stroustrup.com/slashdot_interview.html):

> The flip side of this is that you have to deal with old mistakes and with compatibility problems. For example, ***I consider the C declarator syntax an experiment that failed.*** Nevertheless, I adopted it for C++. The alternatives and improvements I considered at the time would not have improved matters. I rate is as a minor problem. The more serious problem is to maintain closeness of language definitions as C evolves.

but I'd rather have a citation from Ritchie if one exists.  Yes, I tried Googl'ing for it (which is how I found the Stroustrup citation), but nothing for Ritchie.

Comment: "I'm still uncertain about the language declaration syntax, where in declarations, syntax is used that mimics the use of the variables being declared. It is one of the things that draws strong criticism, but it has a certain logic to it." *Dennis M. Ritchie*

Comment: This question seems more appropriate to stackoverflow.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus StackOverflow is for _programming_ questions. This question isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Evil Awesome! Though if you put the quote as an _answer_ to the question rather than a comment, I could mark it as the answer.

Comment: I am glad it helped, but I think that this question is not about the Computer Science per se. It looks like historical quote about the programming language syntax made post factum. Anyway, have you seen Stroustrup's interview? He was convinced that creating C++ was a mistake.

Comment: @Evil There's a _History Stack Exchange_ and a _Computer Science Stack Exchange_, but no _History of Computer Science Stack Exchange_ (which would probably be _way_ too niche). Of the two, I figured that computer scientists would be more likely to know the answer than general historians.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas This also isn't a computer science question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby See my previous response.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas It's a history of computing question, sure. But this is computer science, not computing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby And, again, if there _were_ a history-of-cs or a computing stack exchange, I _would_ have posted it there. But neither exists, so this is the closest match. BTW: this was posted over 2 years ago. Haven't you got anything better to do than post unhelpful comments on an old question?

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Right, but "closest match" doesn't mean "on-topic". How I choose to use my time is none of your business.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fine, you can continue to comment to yourself. You'll no longer receive any responses from me. I hope it's been worth it.